#  Problem while upgrding from 11.10 to 12.04 

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

I am upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 using the Update Manager.
With about 35 minutes left in the "installing" phase of the upgrade, the screen went black, mouse and keyboard dead. Do I need to make a new installation from an ISO CD?  If yes, should I use the 12.04 issue of Ubuntu.

Comment: A new installation is mostly useful than the headache of an upgrade.Now you have a broken system and if you are preferred, a new installation is good anyway.Before that back up the data first.You can try all the tweaks also as your data is safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a new installation by downloading a 12.04 issue from Ubuntu, burn it to a CD or if you have windows use LILI usb creator program (which is freely available) to create a USB bootable disk and do the installation